# C# - Disable CS0444 warning

Tags: c#, warnings

I've this warning because I've created the type :

```
#if COMPACT_FRAMEWORK_3_5

namespace System.Diagnostics
{
    /// <summary>Determines how a class or field is displayed in the debugger variable windows.</summary>
    /// <remarks>See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx </remarks>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Delegate | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = true)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public sealed class DebuggerDisplayAttribute : Attribute
    { /* ... */ }
}
#endif
```

I've created it because I'm on CF.NET and this attribute doesn't exists in it, so I created it in order to customize my debug view (I always debug using CF.NET).

I've tried to add `#pragma warning disable` at the beginning and restore it at the end but doesn't work, I've always a CS0444 warning in VS2k8 ...

How can I fix this?

Thanks

---

### EDIT

I used it like this :

```
#if COMPACT_FRAMEWORK_3_5
#pragma warning disable // 0444

namespace System.Diagnostics
{
    /// <summary>Determines how a class or field is displayed in the debugger variable windows.</summary>
    /// <remarks>See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx </remarks>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Delegate | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = true)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public sealed class DebuggerDisplayAttribute : Attribute
    { /* ... */ }
}
#pragma warning restore // 0444
#endif
```

Comment: Could you show *how* you've tried to use `#pragma warning disable`?

Comment: I suspect you need to disable the warning at the site where you *use* the attribute and not where you *declare* the attribute.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like they removed the warning in VS2010. At least the documentation doesn't contain it in the error/warning list.

Comment: @All : See my edit, I posted how I've tried to use it.

Comment: You need to disable it wherever you use the attribute. Probably the easiest way to do that is globally disabling the warning. It's not that useful anyways.

Comment: And how can I disable it globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example has the number commented out:

```
#pragma warning disable // 0444
```

Eh, don't:

```
#pragma warning disable 444
```

To disable it globally, you use `/nowarn:444` (comma-separate other warnings to disable) with the compiler. If using an IDE there'll probably be somewhere in the project properties to set warnings to disable (Visual Studio has it on the "Build" tab, SharpDevelop has it on the "Compiling" tab, other IDEs will likely have it somewhere similar). Nant scripts have a `<onwarn>` element as an allowed child of `<csc>` (which also has a `nowarn` attribute, but that's deprecated).

I'd avoid global disabling though, after all, doing something that triggers CS0444 is normally a bad idea. In your case above you've a good reason for doing so (you need functionality the compact version doesn't give you) and know that's what you are doing, but if you'd accidentally done it somewhere else, and you'd suppressed warnings, you'll be none the wiser.

Edit: For that matter, I've a policy that I never disable a warning without at least a short comment as to why. An uncommented disabling of a warning can mean "I did something silly here, and then disabled the warning rather than fixed it", the comment can make it clear that this isn't the case, and that there's nothing in need of a fix.

Comment: Yes number is commented out voluntary, with or not with, I've the warning, when not specifying a warning number it will disable ALL warnings, that's why I doesn't understand why I can ignore it ;).

Answer (score 1):

Ermm, perhaps try

```
#pragma warning disable 444
```

instead of commenting the error number? See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of course